# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at java.util.Date.parse

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, mybatis, setter

table column

```
  `start_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL COMMENT '秒杀结束时间',
  `end_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL COMMENT '秒杀结束时间',
  `create_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp COMMENT '创建时间',
```

There are several properties in entity(`com.hxy.entity.Seckill`)

Entity

```
private Date   start_time;
private Date   end_time;
private Date   create_time;
```

Mapper

```
<select id="queryById" resultType="com.hxy.entity.Seckill" parameterType="long">
    SELECT seckill.seckill_id,seckill.name,seckill.number,seckill.start_time,seckill.end_time,seckill.create_time
    FROM
    seckill.seckill
    WHERE seckill_id=#{seckillId}
</select>
```

DAO

```
 Seckill queryById(long seckillid);
```

Service

```
 public Exposer exportSecKillUrl(final long seckillid) {
    Seckill seckill = seckillDao.queryById(seckillid);

    logger.info(seckill.toString());
}
```

Test

```
    @Test
public void getById() throws Exception {
    long    id      = 1000;
    Seckill seckill = secKillService.getById(id);

    logger.info("seckill={}", seckill);
}
```

Log

```
  19:08:34.579 [main] DEBUG o.m.s.t.SpringManagedTransaction -JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@5ef5c734 [wrapping: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@d771cc9]] will not be managed by Spring
  19:08:34.586 [main] DEBUG com.hxy.dao.SeckillDao.queryById -==>  Preparing: SELECT seckill.seckill_id,seckill.name,seckill.number,seckill.start_time,seckill.end_time,seckill.create_time FROM seckill.seckill WHERE seckill_id=? 
  19:08:34.620 [main] DEBUG com.hxy.dao.SeckillDao.queryById -==> Parameters: 1000(Long)
  19:08:34.709 [main] DEBUG com.hxy.dao.SeckillDao.queryById -<==      Total: 1
  19:08:34.713 [main] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils -Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@48793bef]
  19:08:34.715 [main] INFO  c.hxy.service.impl.SecKilServiceimpl -Seckill{seckillid=1000, name='1000元秒杀ipone6', number=100, start_time=null, end_time=null, create_time=null}

  java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.hxy.service.impl.SecKilServiceimpl.exportSecKillUrl(SecKilServiceimpl.java:126)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
```

SQL Directly

```
  SELECT seckill.seckill_id,seckill.name,seckill.number,seckill.start_time,seckill.end_time,seckill.create_time
  FROM
  seckill.seckill
  WHERE seckill_id=1000;
```

Result

```
                               start_time             end_time         create_time
  1000  1000元秒杀ipone6   100 2015-11-01 00:00:00 2015-11-02 00:00:00 2016-06-11 22:05:07
```

Comment: What is type of these three column `start_time, end_time,create_time` in database?

Comment: @Reno I can get the column star_time's value directly by SQL ,so I think the exception happens when spring try to set the value to my bean's property by setter.

Comment: When did this exception happen, `mybatis` result map to java object? Or ?   Post more stack trace exception log please.

Comment: this may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383783/oracle-sql-date-conversion-problem-using-ibatis-via-java-jdbc

Comment: @Reno the stack trace log

Comment: So, either the DAO is null, or the returned seckill is null, depending on which line is line 126 in SecKilServiceimpl.

Comment: @JBNizet I think Mybatis failed to setter "starttime" to entity

Comment: I fix my problem by refactor Entity

--------------------------------------------
      private Date   start_time;
      private Date   end_time;
      private Date   create_time;

--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------
    private Date startTime;
    private Date endTime;
    private Date createTime;
-------------------------------------------
It seems that the framework(mybatis) cannot resolve getter and setter that contains special Character(I failed to use<code> for my code block,so I use ------------------)